# Copying shapefile along a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have multiple cross-sections (point data).
The adjacent cross-sections are very far apart. I want to copy a set of cross-sections at a fixed interval (say n-meters) along a line. At this moment I'm manually doing it using Editor toolbar.

Figure below shows the before and after image.

[image: Manual cross-sections]

Cyan are the original cross-sections and the red ones are the copied (copy of adjacent cross-section)

Is there any way to copy a set of points, at a fixed interval along a line perpendicular to it, in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Comment: please look at this: https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/shifting-features/

Comment: It is not a simple move, involves rotation

Comment: Yes that is correct. My apologies, In my original post, I should have mentioned "polyline" instead of a "line". It involves rotation (based on the polyline)

Comment: To do this would need ArcPy, and for questions about that we need to see a code attempt first.  You can use Python script tools in models, but this may be something more suitable for a Python AddIn anyway.